# Angular Jasmine Unit Test: TypeError: this.sitesTable.renderRows is not a function

Tags: angular

I have following error during simple unit test in Angular/Jasmine/Karma.

```
TypeError: this.sitesTable.renderRows is not a function
```

I have mat-table inside NgForm. I would like to test method where i resetForm and renderRows but it throws this error. It works in normal "not test environment".

TEST:

```
it('should reset Form when resetForm invoked', () => {
    spyOn(component.studyForm, 'resetForm');
    component.resetForm();
    expect(component.studyForm.resetForm).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

Tested Method:

```
resetForm(){
    this.studyForm.resetForm();
    this.ngOnInit();
    this.sitesTable.renderRows();
  }
```

Could i ask you to help me or give me link to article or anything what can be helpful?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found solution and i think it can be useful for someone who have same issue.

Solution: Add MaterialModule and BrowserAnimationsModule to imports in test file.

Solution Description:

I read Angular documentation about TestBed
https://angular.io/guide/testing.
If i understood it right TestBed.configureTestingModule() create completely separated version of Module.
So in my case I have 2 Modules: AppModule and TestBed(something like AppModuleTest)

In this case MaterialModule should be added in both Modules.
BrowserAnimationsModule also should be imported to enable MaterialModule.

I will be really thankful if someone more experienced will correct me or add something more.

Answer (score 0):

Try to instance a new MatTable in your test and set to component.sitesTable.
It's probably that the ViewChild doesn't retrive the MatTable instance in your test. This would be a simple solution. Then you can spyOn the renderRows method.

Good luck!